# Follow the link from PHPDoc in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Imagine there is code like that:

```
<?php

class T
{
    /**
     * {@link http://php.net/count}
     * @link http://php.net/count
     *
     * @param array $inputArray
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public static function count(array $inputArray)
    {
        return count($inputArray);
    }
}
```

If I open a quick documentation window for the method, then there is an HTTP link, which I can click and it'll be opened in browser.

[image: Quick documentation window for method]

But I wonder if there is a way to follow the link from `@link` tag by clicking on it immediately from PhpStorm, without opening the quick documentation window?

I think I remember using this functionality, but I'm not 100% sure, and I could not find any info in the PhpStorm's documentation.

Comment: What is your PhpStorm version exactly (including build number)?

Comment: @LazyOne it's PHPStorm 2016.1 Build #PS-145.258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a bug in PhpStorm v2016.1 final.

It's now [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28548) -- but you have to use **2016.1.1** EAP build or wait until 2016.1.1 final will actually be released.

2016.1.1 EAP (latest for this moment build) can be downloaded [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/04/phpstorm-2016-1-1-eap-145-969/).

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid for not checking the bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click on Windows (and Linux, I suppose) and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-click on OSX opens the URL in the browser.

Comment: Yeah, I know the hotkey :) The problem is that it's not working. Turned out to be a bug.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the key in the question. It works for me but I'm using 2016.1.1 EAP